# Python Decoding NDFD Grib Binary File Similar to Writing then Reading the File Using Open(path, 'wb') and xarray.load_dataset(path, engine='cfgrib')

Tags: python, decode, binaryfiles, grib, ndfd

I have the following code which works:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xarray as xr
import cfgrib

r = requests.get(
    'https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/ST.opnl/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.neast/VP.001-003/ds.wspd.bin', 
    stream=True)

f = open('..\\001_003wspd.grb', 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()

xr_set = xr.load_dataset('..\\001_003wspd.grb', engine="cfgrib")
windspeed_df = xr_set.to_dataframe()
```

What I am is wanting is to avoid writing then reading the file. Something like:

```
grib = r.content.decode()
```

or

```
xr_set = xr.load_dataset(r.content, engine="cfgrib")
```

which both give:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 95: invalid continuation byte
```

I have also tried:

```
grib = resp.content.decode(errors='ignore')
xr_set = xr.open_dataset(grib, engine="cfgrib")
```

which gives:

```
ValueError: embedded null character
```

As well as trying different binary encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the `cfgrib` code, and in particular the `open_file` method, and it seems it only accepts str or os.PathLike[str] objects. So, the `r.content` is read as a path and it goes wrong. If you do not want to store files permanently, you could try :

```
import os

import requests
import xarray as xr
from fs.tempfs import TempFS


def download_and_read_grib(url) -> xr.Dataset:
    with TempFS() as tempfs:
        with requests.get(url) as r:
            path = os.path.join(tempfs._temp_dir, "data.grb")
            with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
            ds = xr.open_dataset(path, engine='cfgrib').load()
    return ds


download_and_read_grib('https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/ST.opnl/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.neast/VP.001-003/ds.wspd.bin')
```

Comment: I was struggling to solve same problem, thanks @cyril for finally putting me on the right track.  I've adapted to use the standard [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) library in lieu of [fs](https://pypi.org/project/fs/).  i.e.,  `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td` and `path = os.path.join(td, 'data.grb')`